# How to open new dynamic form with dropdown menu[Select tag]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I'll try to be specific as possible. I have a dropdown menu[select tag] which gives the user to select 5 options; namely numbers from 1 to 5. Now depending upon the the selected option i want to display a new form with same number of input tags as the option selected

So if the user selects 3 from the dropdown menu, then a sub table will appear at the bottom displaying three input tags. the code is:

```
<select id="formName9" name="blockUnits">
 <option selected="selected" value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
 <option value="4">4</option>
 <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Why tag jQuery if you're not after a jQuery solution? arjuncc's answer is completely valid if you're not using jQuery, but if you are then you may as well use the jQuery solution as it features less lines of code and is more resourceful. Don't tag jQuery if you're not actually using it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I support James Donnelly's answer. If you want it to be pure java script you can use this alternative.

**HTML**

```
 <select id="formName9" name="blockUnits" onchange="addInput()">
     <option selected="selected" value="1" >1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
     <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
    <form>
    <div id="newAdd"> </div>.
    </form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function addElement() {
    var element = document.createElement("input"); //creating input
    element.setAttribute("value", "");//setting its value
    element.setAttribute("name", "newInput");//naming the input
    var foo = document.getElementById("newAdd");
    foo.appendChild(element);//appendign the value into the parant div
}
function addInput(){
    document.getElementById("newAdd").innerHTML="";//clearing the div
     var noInp=parseInt(document.getElementById("formName9").value);
        while(noInp>0)
        {
        addElement();
            noInp--;
        }           
    }
```

here is the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nWtNm/8/)

Answer (score 7):

You'd make use of the `on change` event listener:

```
$('select#formName9').on('change', function() {
    /* Remove the existing input container, if it exists. */
    $('form#container').remove();

    /* Get the selected value and create the new container. */
    var val = $(this).val()
        $container = $('<form id="container"></form>');

    /* Loop through creating input elements based on value. */
    for(i=0;i<val;i++)
    {
        /* Create the new input element. */
        var $input = $('<input type="text"/>');

        /* Append this input element to the container. */
        $input.appendTo($container);
    }

    /* Add container to the page. */
    $container.insertAfter($(this));
})
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/PvJau/1/).

You could then expand upon this to add a default input based on the initially `selected` option:

[Extended JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PvJau/2/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select#formName9').on('change', function() {
var ddVal=$(this).val();
for(i=0;i<ddVal.length;i++)
{
$("#FORMPOSITION").append("<input type='text' name='ddG"+i+"' id='ddVL"+i+"'>");
}
});
```

consider the quotes before executing.

Answer (score 0):

I tried and worked. Try it:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#formName9').change(function() {
                var number = parseInt($('#formName9').val());
                if(number == 3) {
                    alert('3 HERE');
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sort of dynamic example using jQuery and CSS. I've provided a [working jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/HhnrG/2/)

This is the basic idea, you can work off of this and add more inputs if needed.

HTML:

```
<select id="formName9" name="blockUnits">
    <option selected="selected" value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<div id="form1" class="hiddenForm form">Form 1</div>
<div id="form2" class="hiddenForm form">Form 2</div>
<div id="form3" class="hiddenForm form">Form 3</div>
<div id="form4" class="hiddenForm form">Form 4</div>
<div id="form5" class="hiddenForm form">Form 5</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#form1").show()
$("#formName9").change(function () {
    var form = "#form" + $(this).val();
    $(form).siblings(".hiddenForm").hide()
    $(form).show();
});
```

CSS:

```
.form {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px dotted #000;
    margin: 5px;
}
.hiddenForm {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that adding all DIV at the beginning and just SHOW/HIDE them is the best solution. You can easily create the DOM in a JS function...

Comment: You definitely can, that's true. I've never been a big fan of using JS to do that sort of thing, so I __personally__ try not to do that unless it's needed. Why would doing it in JS versus using a simple show/hide be better?

Comment: Ok, It's an alternative way, that's work fine and don't use a lot of JS. I confess.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call, and add the response to the DOM, or directly add the DOM using JS.

For direct DOM, somethink like (using jQuery):

```
$('#formName9').on('change', function() {
   var selected = $(this).val();
   $('#aDomElement').empty();
   for (var i=1; i<=selected; i++) {
       $('#aDomElement').append(
           $('<div id="'+i+'">').html(
                   $('<input>').attr('name', 'input'+i).attr('type', 'text')
           )
        );
   }
});
```

Where `aDomElement` is the ID of an existing HTML element.

Comment: Why would you use Ajax? You aren't making any requests to other pages.

Comment: Ajax was just if you wan't to add some particular treatment (like database call) before to show `input`

Comment: doing the same thing, but without the AJAX, only Jquery. it it works this will the solution

Comment: @JoDev the question didn't mention anything about database calls.

Comment: @Hunain this is basically a copy of [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15518813/1317805) without any explanation of what's going on...

Comment: Of course, but when i answer to a question, i try to give all possibilities, but i only explain the best one (for me ^^).

Comment: -1? A comment would be welcome please, to explain me why you downvote the answer... Just to allow me (and maybe others) to understand what was wrong in my response.